# Display image if post's custom field has specific value

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

How can I display certain image in a post if that post contains a specific custom value.
For example, I have two posts, one has a custom field named `top_post` and its value is `true`. The other one doesn't have that value at all. I want the one with this value set to `true` to have image displayed (an image that shows it's a top post) and the one without the value to show nothing.

I know that the function would be something like "if top_post value is 'true' then display img(url)" but I don't know how to write that function as I'm just a PHP beginner.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: I tried finding the function code on various coding blogs but didn't succeed... Also, I have no function coding experiences and that's why I was asking for a function code.

Comment: Can you show a code you already have?

Comment: Why the down voting? :/
I don't have any code because I don't know what the function should be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Atiaxi's answer, and perhaps make it a bit more readable for you as a beginner in php:

```
if ($top_post == true)
{
    echo "<img src='top_post_image.png'>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='blank.png'>"; //you could also leave this line out if you want 'nothing'
}
```

Comment: How does it know that it has to search for `top_post` in a custom field? Asking that because I tried it and it doesn't work, it goes to `else` i.e. shows blank.png...

Comment: You havn't explained how you are getting your "top_post" value.  E.g. are you reading it from a database? are you getting it from a form?

Comment: As an example, if you are getting it from a form then you would do something like this: 

$top_post = $_POST['top_post'];

Comment: I guess I can use `<?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){get_custom_field_value('top_post',$post->ID, true);} ?>` but I don't know how it can just check the value and not display it.
This is from functions.php: `function get_custom_field_value($szKey,$postId, $bPrint = false) {global $post;
$szValue = get_post_meta($postId, $szKey, true);
if ( $bPrint == false ) return $szValue; else echo $szValue;}`, it's the one referenced with that code above.

Comment: ok, using that code you would do this: <?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){ `$top_post =` get_custom_field_value('top_post',$post->ID, true);} ?>

This will put the value into $top_post of true/false.

Comment: No, that just displays the value of `top_post` custom field. It doesn't check that it says "true", therefore doesn't display an image.
Could you write the complete code that echos the image (top_post_image.png) if the value in `top_post` = "true"?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that you need to use the `$top_post=` part to get the value from the custom fields.  Then after you've done that you need the code from my original post.  Below is full code: (still learning stackoverflow so formatting might not be right)

if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') )
{ 
    //set $top_post to true or false.
    $top_post = get_custom_field_value('top_post',$post->ID, true); 
}

if ($top_post == true)
{
    echo "<img src='top_post_image.png'>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='blank.png'>"; //you could also leave this line out if you want 'nothing'
}

Comment: OK, here's a final code that works:
`<div id="test"><?php $top_post = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_post', true); if($top_post == 'true'): echo "<img src='absolute path to top_image_post.jpg'>"; else: echo ""?> <?php endif; ?> </div>`.
Don't know why but I can't use wiggly brackets with `echo`, it gives me an error.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, I think what you need to keep in mind is that you're using PHP to generate the HTML on the page.  So if you want an image to show up if a certain condition is true, you only generate the HTML for that image if the condition is true:

```
if(top_post)
    echo "<img src='top_post_image.png'>"
```